# What's the closest jQuery approximation to YUI's DataTable?

Tags: jquery, html-table, yui, inline-editing, progressive-enhancement

My two highest priorities are progressive enhancement and inline editing. I've found progressive enhancement ([DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/api)) and inline editing ([jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)), but not both. Support for jQuery UI themes would be nice, but is a lower priority.

UPDATE: Here's an example of what I'm imagining the solution would resemble:

```
<table summary="A table full of example tabular data">
  <caption>My Table to Progressively Enhance</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="colA">Column A</th>
      <th id="colB">Column B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td headers="colA">foo</td>
      <td headers="colB">bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td headers="colA">argle</td>
      <td headers="colB">bargle</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

… insert jquery datatable stuff here …

<script type="text/javascript">
    progressivelyEnhanceMyTable();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest release of jqGrid, we now get [`tableToGrid`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:table_to_jqgrid), which solves the grid-from-markup problem quite nicely.

Answer (score 5):

I think [jqGrid](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqGrids) would be a pretty good fit.

UPDATE:

You can use code like this to convert your table to a javascript object

```
var $table = $('table'); // select your table
var data = []; // instantiate the data array
$('tr', $table).each(function(i, item){ // loop through the table rows
    obj = {} // create the object to append to the data array
    obj.name = $('td:eq(0)',$(this)).text().trim(); 
    obj.desc = $('td:eq(1)',$(this)).text().trim();
    data += obj; // add the object to the array
});
```

and then tack it on like in the [loading array data example](http://www.trirand.com/jqgrid35/jqgrid.html)

```
for(var i=0;i<=data.length;i++) $("#datagrid").addRowData(i+1,data[i]);
```

Comment: How do I create a jqGrid from a `table` full of data?

Comment: Do you mean html table or database table?

Comment: If you can supply the source code you are working with, I can help you better.

Comment: I mean an html table. I want to send the data down with the initial response as a semantically correct `table`. Then I want to use jQuery to fancy it up and provide inline-editing capabilities. Reading through the jqGrid docs, I was left with the distinct impression that there was no way to take a `table` tag that already had all the data and create a jqGrid from it.

Comment: Try it with the example I've provided now. You'll want to make it more robust probably. Like loop the <th> to make the columns, but I think the code above should help.

Comment: Clever. I was thinking of something more out-of-the-box, but I can probably make this work. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the line `data += obj;` actually be `data.push(obj);`?  As it is now it converts data to an empty string and then appends strings to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin to datatables called [jquery-datatables-editable](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/) which adds inline editing.